# What effect do the "Developer" settings have, when the store is running in production mode?

Tags: magento2, configuration, developer-mode

In my fresh Magento 2 install: When in production mode, the settings under `Store->Configuration->Developer` are not shown at all.

When in developer mode, they appear, and some options specifically note that they are `Not available in production mode`, while others note that they have no effect in developer mode. For example, `Minification is not applied in developer mode.`.

**This leads me to wonder:**

**1.** Do any of the settings shown in the Developer options have an effect when the store is in production mode?

**2.** Why are the "Developer" options are not accessible when the store is in production mode.